# stri_replace_all_fixed equivalent: Replace values based on list

Tags: c#, python, regex, string, perl

R has a powerful string processing package called [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html). In particular, I would like to achieve the same as with [stri_replace_all_fixed](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.1.6/topics/stri_replace_all) function: replace matches based on a list/dictionary in let's say Perl/PHP/Python or C#.

```
#install.packages("stringi")
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
    c("quick", "brown", "fox"), c("slow",  "black", "bear"), vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

Outputs:

> "The slow black bear jumped over the lazy dog."

Comment: What would the output be in your example?

Comment: @afc11hn Good point, I have added a more detailed R sample with the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash to map words to be replaced with their replacements.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

my @words     = qw(quick brown fox);
my @change_to = qw(slow black bear);

my %replacement;
@replacement{@words} = @change_to;  # populate hash: quick => 'slow', ...

my $pattern = join '|', map { quotemeta } sort { length $a < length $b } @words;

$string =~ s/($pattern)/$replacement{$1}/g;

say $string;
```

Note that we need to [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) components of the pattern by their [length](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html), so that longer words come before shorter ones; otherwise, with `/no|none/` the `'no'` can get replaced in the word `'none'`.

Wrap it in a subroutine with the desired interface, say

```
sub_name($string, \@words, \@change_to);
```

Comment: Awesome, I like that!

Comment: @wp78de Great :)  I added an explanation (for sorting, by length)

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is:

1. create a dictionary mapping words to their replacements
2. compile a regex matching all keys in the dictionary
3. Match the regex, and replace each match with the dictionary value of the matched key.

In Perl, such a function would look like this:

```
sub replace_all {
  my ($string, %replacements) = @_;
  # Assemble the regex. 
  # Sort reverse so that longer keys are matched first.
  # Quotemeta each key in order to escape special characters.
  my $pattern = join '|', map quotemeta, reverse sort keys %replacements;
  $string =~ s/($pattern)/$replacements{$1}/g;  # replace all
  return $string;
}
```

Test:

```
use Test::More;
my $output = replace_all(
  "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
  quick => 'slow',
  brown => 'black',
  fox => 'bear');
my $expected = "The slow black bear jumped over the lazy dog.";
is $output, $expected;
done_testing;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can pass a replacement function to `re.sub` to return a string to be used as a substitute for a given match. We can create a dict containing all the patterns and their replacements first and then write a lookup function which gives use the suitable replacement string.

```
import re


def stri_replace_all_fixed(stri, patterns, replacements):
    pattern_to_replacement = {p: r for p, r in zip(patterns, replacements)}

    def switch(match):
        return pattern_to_replacement[match.group(0)]

    # To make sure that longer patterns are matched first
    # we sort the list by the length of its elements and reverse it
    patterns = sorted(patterns, key=len, reverse=True)

    print(re.sub('|'.join(patterns), switch, stri))


pattern = "quick", "brown", "fox"
replace = "slow", "black", "bear"
stri_replace_all_fixed("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.", pattern, replace)
```

Comment: "_I'm not absolutely sure if this is useful_" -- it is absolutely necessary, but the way you have it is **wrong**, and it's wrong in Perl in this way, too. The pattern  `p1|p2|...` need be built so that the longest words come first; otherwise a short sub-word can get replaced wrongly (`no` in `nothing`, when `nothing` happens before `no` in target). However, in Perl `sort` by default does it _alphabetically_ and here we need it by length; see my answer. In Python you also must tell it how it should be `sorted` and you want to use `key` parameter.  Fix it please.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thank you for explaining why this is so important.